# Fixing a preg_match rule not to match the start of a tag "<"

Tags: regex, youtube, preg-match, expression

I have this preg_match rule that transforms plain youtube link into an actual player html code:

```
preg_match('#(?:http://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com/(?:v/|watch\?)|youtu\.be/)([\w-]+)(?:\S+)?#', $text, $youtube_match);
```

1) It doesn't work if I have a tag right after the video link, let's say a br tag: `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rUGhlNCNho<br />` , it probably thinks that the `<br` is part of the URL.

2) How should I modify the rule to match also a mixed order of the url variable, e.g:

`http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=4rUGhlNCNho` 
instead of 
`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rUGhlNCNho`

Comment: How can I do that? The code was made by someone else, I am not good with regex at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If iam right, you only need the parameter v= to generate and embed video

```
preg_match('#(?:http://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com/(?:v/|watch\?)|youtu\.be/)[a-z0-9A-Z\-_\=\&\%\?]*v\=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)#', $text, $youtube_match);
```

Comment: Thank you, that does the trick, I added an extra `([a-zA-Z0-9=&_]+)?` at the end so that it also matches (but not fetch) additional variables after the v=foo: `preg_match('#(?:http://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com/(?:v/|watch\?)|youtu\.be/)[a-z0-9A-Z\-_\=\&\%\?]*v\=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([a-zA-Z0-9=&_]+)?#', $text, $youtube_match);`

Answer (score 0):

My final code after GreenRover's answer:

```
preg_match('#(?:http://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com/(?:v/|watch\?)|youtu\.be/)[a-z0-9A-Z\-_\=\&\%\?]*v\=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([a-zA-Z0-9=&_]+)?#', $text, $youtube_match);
```

This matched these different situations (ending in new line with additional text, ending in a BR tag, etc):

`"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rUGhlNCNho&feature=player_embedded"
"http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=4rUGhlNCNho "
"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rUGhlNCNho&feature=player_embedded\nETC"
"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rUGhlNCNho&feature=player_embedded "
"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rUGhlNCNho&feature=player_embedded<br />"`

Answer (score 0):

Since `PCRE` dosent support variable repition inside lookbehind, you can use this

```
(?:http://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com/(?:v/|watch\?)|youtu\.be/)([\w-]+)(?:\S+)?$(?<!>)
```

Other regex flavour , instead you can use this

```
(?:http://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com/(?:v/|watch\?)|youtu\.be/)([\w-]+)(?:\S+)?$(?<!<[^>]*>)
```